# TypeError: quit() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given (keyboard bind)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have this python code:

```
def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Simple menu")
        menubar = Menu(self.parent)
        self.parent.config(menu=menubar)

        #file menu
        fileMenu = Menu(menubar)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.quit, accelerator="Ctrl+Q")
        self.bind_all("<Control-q>", self.quit)

    def quit(self):
        sys.exit(0)
```

When I select Exit from the menu, it works fine. However, when I press `ctrl+q`, I get this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1538, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: quit() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

What the heck is going on?

Comment: By looking ur code i can say one thing,indentation of the function quit(self) is not proper.I am sure if u try to run this module it will throw syntax error.

Comment: Sorry, it's in a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When tk calls a bound event function, it passes an event with all the information described [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/event-handlers.html).  As a simplification, when tk calls Button click command functions, it does not pass an event, because it is not needed.  The event is known to be a Button-1 click and the location of the cursor within the button is almost never relevant.  (If one wants to handle other mouse events within the button or if one cares about the mouse location, one should explicitly bind an event handler.)

In your case, since you do not care about the event object, add an optional event parameter defaulted to None.  This will 'swallow' the event when the function is invoked with ^Q instead of the button.

```
    def quit(self, event=None):
        sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution, use lambdas:

```
self.bind('<Control-q>', lambda e: self.quit())
```

Note:
Terry Jan Reedy Mentioned about how the event binding will pass extra arguments (event details), this is why the quit function is erring.